D3D11 hardware screen recording with ffmpeg using Intel H264 QSV hardware encoding
I'm trying to screen record using ffmpeg and having it all done via hardware on my Intel integrated graphics.
Specs
For reference, here are my specs:

Windows 11 Pro Version 10.0.22631 Build 22631
Model: Dell Inc. OptiPlex 3090
Processor: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-1115G4 @ 3.00GHz, 2995 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)
Terminal: Windows Terminal using Windows Powershell

In this wiki, it looked like I could use the "Windows 8+ Desktop Duplication API" to be "directly encoded by a compatible hardware encoder" — so I thought that I could use h264_qsv to encode, allowing me to record without much performance overhead costs.
Attempt 1
I've tried copying one of the command examples, but it didn't work:
ffmpeg -init_hw_device d3d11va -filter_complex ddagrab=0 

Output:
ffmpeg version 2024-05-02-git-71669f2ad5-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 13.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libaribcaption --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libxevd --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxeve --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-dxva2 --enable-d3d11va --enable-d3d12va --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-libvpl --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-vaapi --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      59. 16.101 / 59. 16.101
  libavcodec     61.  5.103 / 61.  5.103
  libavformat    61.  3.103 / 61.  3.103
  libavdevice    61.  2.100 / 61.  2.100
  libavfilter    10.  2.101 / 10.  2.101
  libswscale      8.  2.100 /  8.  2.100
  libswresample   5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libpostproc    58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
Stream mapping:
  ddagrab:default -> Stream #0:0 (h264_qsv)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'Parsed_ddagrab_0' and the filter 'auto_scale_0'
[fc#0 @ 000001e4ed4393c0] Error configuring filter graph: Function not implemented
[fc#0 @ 000001e4ed4393c0] Task finished with error code: -40 (Function not implemented)
[fc#0 @ 000001e4ed4393c0] Terminating thread with return code -40 (Function not implemented)
[vost#0:0/h264_qsv @ 000001e4ed454000] Could not open encoder before EOF
[vost#0:0/h264_qsv @ 000001e4ed454000] Task finished with error code: -22 (Invalid argument)
[vost#0:0/h264_qsv @ 000001e4ed454000] Terminating thread with return code -22 (Invalid argument)
[out#0/matroska @ 000001e4ed453280] Nothing was written into output file, because at least one of its streams received no packets.
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=       0KiB time=N/A bitrate=N/A speed=N/A
Conversion failed!

Attempt 2
I then tried copying one of the command examples in the linked ddagrab wiki page, but also no luck.
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i ddagrab -c:v h264_qsv output.mkv

Output:
ffmpeg version 2024-05-02-git-71669f2ad5-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 13.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libaribcaption --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libxevd --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxeve --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-dxva2 --enable-d3d11va --enable-d3d12va --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-libvpl --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-vaapi --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      59. 16.101 / 59. 16.101
  libavcodec     61.  5.103 / 61.  5.103
  libavformat    61.  3.103 / 61.  3.103
  libavdevice    61.  2.100 / 61.  2.100
  libavfilter    10.  2.101 / 10.  2.101
  libswscale      8.  2.100 /  8.  2.100
  libswresample   5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libpostproc    58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
Input #0, lavfi, from 'ddagrab':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Video: wrapped_avframe, d3d11, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn
File 'output.mkv' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (wrapped_avframe (native) -> h264 (h264_qsv))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'Parsed_null_0' and the filter 'auto_scale_0'
[vf#0:0 @ 00000115e105bd40] Error reinitializing filters!
[vf#0:0 @ 00000115e105bd40] Task finished with error code: -40 (Function not implemented)
[vf#0:0 @ 00000115e105bd40] Terminating thread with return code -40 (Function not implemented)
[vost#0:0/h264_qsv @ 00000115e105aa00] Could not open encoder before EOF
[vost#0:0/h264_qsv @ 00000115e105aa00] Task finished with error code: -22 (Invalid argument)
[vost#0:0/h264_qsv @ 00000115e105aa00] Terminating thread with return code -22 (Invalid argument)
[out#0/matroska @ 00000115e1054b80] Nothing was written into output file, because at least one of its streams received no packets.
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=       0KiB time=N/A bitrate=N/A speed=N/A
Conversion failed!

My main problem is that I don't know how to use really any of these encoders and the examples I've found above don't work with me. What command should I use to screen record all with hardware acceleration on my Intel system? I don't care about any presets or other options at the moment.
Is there also a way to record audio? When I tried to use -f dshow -i audio="Stereo Mix (Realtek(R) Audio)" by itself, which I made sure was turned on in Windows' settings and named correctly, it didn't work (is it because I'm using Bluetooth headphones that isn't connected to Realtek's system?). Should this question be made separately than this one?

It's not working because the pixel format (output) of ddagrab is d3d11. d3d11 pixel format is not supported as input to h264_qsv encoder (should be qsv). FFmpeg doesn't support the conversion from  d3d11 to qsv. (adding -loglevel debug we can see that the output of ddagrab is pixfmt:d3d11). ddagrab is working with NVIDIA because h264_nvenc supports d3d11 input pixel format (check by executing ffmpeg -h encoder=h264_nvenc). We may use gdigrab with h264_qsv, but it's much less efficient.

less efficient is ok, but is there a way to capture just a portion of the desktop with gdigrab?
